# Switching between Class Frames Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-layout

Main/Parent Class

```
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk): #Root Window
    def __init__(self):
        #main set up
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("700x700")
        self.title('Wuiz')

        #widgets
        #Trying to switch between "frames", have to comment out so they all arent on one window
        #self.Homepage = Homepage(self) 
        self.Weatherpage = Weatherpage(self)
        



        self.mainloop()
```

This Being the main class followed by Frame classes:

WeatherPage Frame/Class -> Holding widget elements, labels, buttons, etc.. then packing it to the main root window

```
class Weatherpage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Back Button at corner => to homepage

        backbutton = Button(self, text="Back", fg="black", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=30)

        ....etc ...

        self.pack(expand=True, fill="both") # Problem probably here
```

Then the info class/frame -> Again Holding widget elements, labels, buttons, etc.. then packing it to the main root window

```
class Infopage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
   
        backbutton = Button(self, text="Back", fg="black", font=("Helvetica", 10),
                            width=30)  # Back button does nothing
        backbutton.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
        ..... etc...
        self.pack(expand=True, fill="both") # Problem probably here
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkinterApp()
```

Do you guys know any methods or soultions/ways to switch frames based of this? I think it might be how I am packing the classes to the root window, I probably need to switch it off and on somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method to switch pages, and remove the `self.pack` call in each of the page classes. The main app should be responsible for adding and removing the page in the root window.

Then it's just a matter of tracking the current page, and when switching it remove it and pack the new page. It might look something like this:

```
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk): #Root Window
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.current_page = None
        ...
        self.Homepage = Homepage(self) 
        self.Weatherpage = Weatherpage(self)
        ...
        self.switch_page(self.HomePage)

    def switch_page(self, new_page):
        if self.current_page is not None:
            self.current_page.pack_forget()
        self.current_page = new_page
        self.current_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

A variation would be to *not* create the pages initially, and instead pass in the classname of the new page. `switch_page` can then destroy the old page, create the new, and pack it:

```
    def switch_page(self, new_page_cls):
        if self.current_page is not None:
            self.current_page.destroy()
        self.current_page = new_page_cls(self)
        self.current_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```